# Update table after ajax with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

i'll start by saying i saw there is lots of information about this topic but i just couldn't find one solid answer to make it clear what will consider to be best practice when trying to update table after Ajax call.

I have an HTML table which i want to update with new data after user generates ajax call by selecting date range.
After range is chosen Ajax call creates new table and i update the DOM like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#selecDate').on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){

  range = getRange() ;

  $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: '/revenue',
               data: {'start' : range[0], 'end' : range[1]},
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function(response){
                updateTable(response);
               },
               error: function(response){
                   console.log('error:' + response);
               },
             });
});
});
```

`updateTable(response)` - the function that's being called when the response accepted:
function updateTable(response){

```
var table = '<table class="table table-bordered data-table sortable" id="rev-table"><thead>';
table += '<tr><th colspan="10">Income</th><th colspan="9">Spent</th>';
table += '<tr><th>Website Name</th><th>Google</th>...LOTS OF LINES
var total_spent= response[website]['total_spent'];...LOTS OF LINES
table += '<tr><td>' + website + '</td>';
table += '</tr>';
}
table += '</tbody></table>';
$('#rev-table-cont').html(table);
```

it's a long table so i chopped a big part but i guess you got the idea...
wherever i wrote LOTS OF LINES, they all do pretty much the same thing
**The problem:**
I used to be able to sort the table with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#rev-table').DataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "processing": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sDom": '<""l>t<"F"fp>'
        });
    $('select').select2();

    $('.active').removeClass("active");
    $('#revenueReport').addClass("active");

});
```

But now after creating the new table and updating the DOM with this line

```
$('#rev-table-cont').html(table);
```

the table is not sortable anymore, the code takes no effect and i have no errors in the console.
I found some leads about this all topic like this link: 
https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload(), or in many question here, but it just something that i cant get a clear answer about i should i solve this problem..does creating a new table like i am doing wil consider to be best practice or is there another way?
why is the table not sortable anymore after ajax call?
any lead will be very helpfull...thx!

Comment: It will be better to generate the table structure as a return / output of the ajax function (server side) itself and just display it when the data is ready using the javascript function.

Comment: @Debashis actually I think exactly the opposite is true, and the structure of most web-based software architectures now backs this up. A good example is when the server-side is an API of some sort - it should be concerned only with the data itself. How the data is presented is the responsibility of the client-side. Even within a single application, it's good practice - that way for instance you can re-use the same (ajax) data source in several places. If you want to then use the same presentation in multiple places, you make a re-usable client-side component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown it, but I assume that when the page loads, there is a table with id "rev-table" which is a child of the "rev-table-cont" element. This table has the DataTable functionality applied to it (as per your script).

The problem is, after the ajax is applied, you create a new `<table>` element to replace it, but you don't give it an id.

There are a couple of solutions:
1) Change `<table class="table table-bordered data-table sortable">` in your `updateTable` method so it gives the table the right id: `<table class="table table-bordered data-table sortable" id="rev-table">`. Then since it's effectively a new element, you will probably need to re-apply the DataTable functionality to it (i.e. using the same `$('#rev-table').DataTable(...` code as you already have.

This has a couple of disadvantages - you might end up duplicating some code you don't need to, and probably any existing sorting/filtering etc. settings that the user had set on the table will be destroyed, which might annoy them.

2) This is the option I would go for: Don't delete and recreate the table, only alter the rows within it. Change the function along these lines:

```
function updateTable(response)
{
  var tableBody = $("#rev-table tbody");
  tableBody.empty(); //delete all the existing rows (from the body only, not the header)

  //here, process your response data to create new rows. You can create a new row like this:
  var row = $("<tr/>");
  //now go through your data items and append all the necessary cells. You can create a cell, and append it to the row something like this:
  $("<td/>", { text: response[website]['total_spent'] }).appendTo(row);
  //repeat that for each cell you need. Then once you have all the cells, append the row to the table:
  row.appendTo(tableBody);
  //and repeat that for each row you need
}
```